# MS Graph - trying to create an upload session but getting resource not found error for shared document library

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-api

**Problem**

I have a Sharepoint Document library located at:

https://my-dough-main.sharepoint.com/widgets/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

I'm trying to programmatically (in c#) create an upload session.  But I'm getting the error "resource could not be found"

**Code**

```
 private readonly siteName string = "my-dough-main.sharepoint.com:/sites/widgets:";
 private readonly string largeBlobsDocumentLibraryID = "57575757575-1ccc-4a44-b88e-5ef0fb75249b";

 // Create the upload session
 //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0
 // itemPath does not need to be a path to an existing item
 var uploadSession =  await _graphServiceClient.Site[siteName.]Drives[largeBlobsDocumentLibraryID]
     .ItemWithPath("thebogusfile.mp4")
     .CreateUploadSession(uploadProps)
     .Request()
     .PostAsync();
```

As far as how I got the ID, I ran this query in Graph Explorer:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/my-dough-main.sharepoint.com:/sites/widgets:/Drives
```

In the result set, I grabbed the ID for the "shared documents" library.

```
    {
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-07T05:30:15Z",
        "description": "",
        "id": "this is the value I'm trying",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-24T13:54:18Z",
        "name": "Documents",
        "webUrl": "https://my-dough-main.sharepoint.com/sites/widgets/Shared%20Documents",
        "driveType": "documentLibrary",
        "createdBy": {
            "user": {
                "displayName": "System Account"
            }
        },
        "lastModifiedBy": {
            "user": {
                "email": "jdoe@outlook.com",
                "id": "guid",
                "displayName": "Doe john"
            }
        },
        "owner": {
            "user": {
                "email": "jdoe@outlook.com",
                "id": "guid",
                "displayName": "Doe John"
            }
        },
        "quota": {
            "deleted": 0,
            "remaining": 27485528222812,
            "state": "normal",
            "total": 27487790694400,
            "used": 2262471588
        }
    },
```

Can someone tell me where I've strayed?  All the examples Ive seen so far use the Me location but how do you write to other locations?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the id, try to run the below query in graph explorer. Check if you could get the library.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drvie-id}
```

If you could get the library, then change your code to this:

```
var uploadSession =await graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].Root
     .ItemWithPath("thebogusfile.mp4")
     .CreateUploadSession()
     .Request()
     .PostAsync();
```